# "This post has been deleted" message while viewing a post in a deleted state

Tags: feature-request, bug, deleted-posts

While viewing a recently deleted post, I got a "This post has been deleted - click to refresh the page" message. I was confused because I was already viewing the post in a "deleted state". I figured, it must have been undeleted and re-deleted; and checking the timeline of the post confirmed so. I managed to reproduce this with my of my own posts:

[image]

I don't think that (re-)deleting a post should trigger a notification for users who are viewing the post in a "deleted state" unless they also get notified when the post is *undeleted*, first.

So, I suggest one of two things should happen here:

- Add a similar notification for when a post is undeleted. Or...
- Remove the "re-deleted notification" for consistency and to avoid confusion.

Comment: Related: [“This post has been deleted” banner appears multiple times if post is undeleted between deletions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402433/4642212).

Comment: While it would be a good and reasonable feature request to add a notification of the undeletion, the issue described here of getting a notification of a deletion is [tag:status-bydesign], IMO. We *should* be notified of the new deletion. It's a deletion. It happened. WE're being notified of it. That banner on the post is how we are notified of it. This is not a bug.

Comment: @Makyen It creates a confusing scenario for lower-rep users. <10k users see a different message "This post has been deleted *and is no longer viewable*". A <10k user seeing their own post or a deleted question they've answered may believe that a mod or someone else has decided to make it so that it can no longer be viewed by its author, and (especially if they don't know they can click to refresh since the message doesn't prompt for that) be left wondering why that was, or think it's a bug since they can continue to see it even afterwards.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog OK. Then there's an issue that the prompt for < 10k users needs to take that into account when the user can view *that* deleted post, not that it's wrong for them to have gotten a notice at all. That's not what this bug report/feature request is about. If you feel that's an issue, then post a new bug/feature request that actually addresses that issue.